# Plotting Away and Home Goal Difference for Crystal Palace 2020/21

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, vega-lite

[image]

Using javascript, vega editor and this data: https://github.com/StanWaldron/StanWaldron.github.io/blob/main/final.csv, which I got from SportDataAPI and organised using pandas, I have attempted to make a graph that plots Crystal Palace's home and away goal differences over the course of the 2020/21 season. As you can see though, I can't get a smooth plot.

The issue seems to be that the NaNs in the data are being put in as 0s for home games when they have played away and vice versa. When trying to resolve this by looping through like so:

```
for c in final['Home_GD']:
    if math.isnan(c) == True:
        c = 0.0
```

It doesn't seem to change the data at all. If this worked, I would just be able to  simply add it to the previous value and plot it that way, for every game.

In the javascript side I have also used layers, but have struggled to find any way of separating the data completely and then using two different data sources which I can layer on the same graph.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",

  "title": {
      "text": "Home and Away Goal Difference For Crystal Palace 2020/21",
      "subtitle":["Exclusively in the Premier League"],
      "subtitleFontStyle":"italic",
      "subtitleFontSize":10,
      "anchor": "start",
      "color": "black"},

  "data": {
      "url":
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanWaldron/StanWaldron.github.io/main/final.csv"
   },

   "repeat": {"layer": ["Away_GD", "Home_GD"]},

   "height": 300,
   "width": 300,

   "spec": {
      "mark": {
          "type":"line",
          "strokeWidth":2},

      "encoding": {
          "x": {
              "field": "Date",
              "type": "temporal",
              "title":null,
              "axis":{
                 "grid": false
          }},

          "y": {
              "field": {"repeat": "layer"},
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": null},

          "color": {
              "datum": {"repeat": "layer"},
              "scale": {"range": ["blue", "red"]},
              "legend": {
                "orient":"top-left",
                "fillColor":"white"}}
              }
          }
  }
```

Comment: As much I understood the problem, 1st is the plot is not smooth , so does this mean you want the lines to curve ? Also I didn't understood the part of seperating the data in layers. Can you explain more on that part ?

Comment: I don't want them to be curved, I would just like them to move between the values on Home_GD and Away_GD only, so if they had a home match, then away, then home that went from -1 to -2 just on the home games, I would like a line between these points, over the course of the 2 weeks between them, and not one that goes to 0 for the away game in between. What I meant by the layers was that ideally I would have a layer with just the home goal difference and one with the away goal difference as they have different dates and when they are on the same table it tries to fill them in, but I can't seem

Comment: to merge these. I hope this is a bit clearer, sorry for not being so in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this by filtering each value individually within a layer; here's an example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanWaldron/StanWaldron.github.io/main/final.csv"
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["Home_GD", "Away_GD"], "as": ["key", "Goals"]}],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "Goals", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.key == 'Home_GD' && datum.Home_GD != ''"}],
      "mark": "line"
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.key == 'Away_GD' && datum.Away_GD != ''"}],
      "mark": "line"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]